# LockBits in Qt. How to implement?

Tags: c++, qt, pointers, bitmap, lockbits

Please tell me this analogue in Qt. How to implement this in Qt? Thx!

```
BitmapData btmData= currentRegionMap.LockBits(new Rectangle(x, y, width, height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, currentRegionMap.PixelFormat);
byte* a = (byte*)btmData.Scan0.ToPointer();
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to do this in Qt. In Qt, the `LockBits` is a No-Op. You need to be using the `QImage` class, that's about it. You can paint on a `QImage` by starting a `QPainter` on it, or by tweaking its binary data. Eventually you convert it to a `QPixmap` and you can draw it on the screen (in a widget or window).